# Github : How to list milestone updates for an issue

Tags: github, github-api

How to list for a specific ticket the current milestone and its precedent assigned ones if applicable (+ date of each milestone update) ? I checked in the github API (https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue) and I can extract the current milestone but not the previous assigned ones (if they exist). Any idea ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Issues Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#list-events-for-an-issue). To test this I went to a test issue and:

1. Added milestone `new`
2. Added milestone `two`

After using that endpoint to query the API I got three events, two with type `milestoned` and one `demilestoned`. The endpoint allows you to filter for those events specifically to remove noise on very active issues. Here is an example of the reply (with obfuscated data)

```
[
  {
    "id": 2193329921,  
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/myRepo/issues/events/2193329921",
    "actor": {
      "login": "myuser",
      "id": 1192590,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjExOTI1OTA=",    
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/myuser",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": true
    },
    "event": "milestoned",
    "commit_id": null,
    "commit_url": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-11T09:42:00Z",
    "milestone": {
      "title": "new"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2193330104,    
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/myRepo/issues/events/2193330104",
    "actor": {
      "login": "myuser",
      "id": 1192590,  
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/myuser",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": true
    },
    "event": "demilestoned",
    "commit_id": null,
    "commit_url": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-11T09:42:04Z",
    "milestone": {
      "title": "new"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2193330105,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/myRepo/issues/events/2193330105",
    "actor": {
      "login": "myuser",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/myuser",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/myuser/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": true
    },
    "event": "milestoned",
    "commit_id": null,
    "commit_url": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-11T09:42:04Z",
    "milestone": {
      "title": "second"
    }
  }
]
```